# Aggregate one entry into multiple groups

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using Google's BigQuery to extract data from the GDELT database, to extract the average tone of the news containing a given country. I have a working SQL query

```
SELECT   date, 
         Avg(Float(tone)) tone 
FROM     ( 
                SELECT integer(regexp_replace(String(date), r'\d{6}$', '')) date, 
                       regexp_replace(v2tone, r',.*', '')                   tone, 
                FROM   [gdelt-bq:gdeltv2.gkg_partitioned] 
                WHERE  _partition_load_time BETWEEN timestamp('2016-07-06') AND    timestamp('2016-07-07') 
                AND    ( 
                              v2locations LIKE '%Spain%')) 
GROUP BY date, 
         country 
ORDER BY country, 
         date
```

But I need to do these queries for a lot of different countries, so I thought maybe I would be able to download all my data on one single query, and I think I am almost there. For an example with two countries:

```
SELECT   date, 
         country, 
         Avg(Float(tone)) tone 
FROM     ( 
                SELECT integer(regexp_replace(String(date), r'\d{6}$', '')) date, 
                       regexp_replace(v2tone, r',.*', '')                   tone, 
                       regexp_extract(v2locations, r'(Spain|Chile)')        country 
                FROM   [gdelt-bq:gdeltv2.gkg_partitioned] 
                WHERE  _partition_load_time BETWEEN timestamp('2016-07-06') AND    timestamp('2016-07-07') 
                AND    ( 
                              v2locations LIKE '%Spain%' 
                       OR     v2locations LIKE '%Chile%')) 
GROUP BY date, 
         country 
ORDER BY country, 
         date
```

Now, the problem here is that for the entries that have both *Chile* and *Spain* need to be averaged in both the groups for *Spain* and *Chile*. As the code is now, I get the correct results for *Chile*, since it comes first alphabetically, but obviously the results for *Spain* are wrong, since the entries with both countries have been averaged into the *Chile* group.

My question is: How can I group the entries that has both the terms *Spain* and *Chile* in the V2Locations column in the both groups? Is it possible to do that?

EDIT: 
While the answers below do answer my question, they do also lead to pretty high costs. Then what I am doing now is making the aggregations locally, to be able to take advantage of the partition featrues of the GDELT database. That is, I exctract the average tone for the different intersections of the countries, as well as the number of observations. This allows for computing the actual country means locally (not on BigQuery). As the amount of data exctrated increases, this takes a long time to compute, but it saves quite a bit on costs, and allows for the extraction of data of one extra country at zero extra cost.

```
SELECT date,  
       concat(IF(regexp_match(country,'Cataluna'),'Cataluna',''),
              IF(regexp_match(country,'Chile'),'Chile',''),'') country, 
       AVG(FLOAT(tone)) Tone, 
       count(tone) num,
FROM (
       SELECT INTEGER(REGEXP_REPLACE(STRING(DATE), r'\d{6}$', '')) date,
              REGEXP_REPLACE(V2Tone, r',.*', '') tone, 
       V2Locations country,
       FROM [gdelt-bq:gdeltv2.gkg_partitioned]
       WHERE _PARTITION_LOAD_TIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2016-05-01')
                                         AND TIMESTAMP('2016-10-23')
       AND (V2Locations like '%Cataluna%'
           OR V2Locations like '%Chile%')) 
GROUP BY date, country
ORDER BY country, date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below (BigQuery Legacy SQL mode)

```
SELECT DATE, country, AVG(FLOAT(tone)) Tone
FROM (
  SELECT INTEGER(REGEXP_REPLACE(STRING(DATE), r'\d{6}$', '')) AS DATE,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(V2Tone, r',.*', '') tone,
    country 
  FROM [gdelt-bq:gdeltv2.gkg_partitioned] gkg 
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT country FROM 
      (SELECT 'Chile' AS country),
      (SELECT 'Spain' AS country)
  ) c
  WHERE _PARTITION_LOAD_TIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2016-07-07') AND TIMESTAMP('2016-07-07') 
  AND gkg.V2Locations LIKE CONCAT('%', country, '%') 
) x
GROUP BY DATE, country 
ORDER BY country, DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky.  Here is one method that uses a `JOIN` to a derived table to find the match to countries:

```
SELECT date, c.country, AVG(FLOAT(tone)) Tone
FROM (SELECT INTEGER(REGEXP_REPLACE(STRING(DATE), r'\d{6}$', '')) as date,
             REGEXP_REPLACE(V2Tone, r',.*', '') tone,
             c.country 
      FROM [gdelt-bq:gdeltv2.gkg_partitioned] gkg CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT 'Chile' as country UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Spain' as country
           ) c
           ON gkg.V2Locations LIKE CONCAT('%', c.country, '%')
      WHERE _PARTITION_LOAD_TIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2016-07-06') AND
            TIMESTAMP('2016-07-07')
     ) x
GROUP BY date, country 
ORDER BY country, date
```

Comment: First of all: Thanks a lot. Second: as is, the code does not work on Google's BigQuery, but I would like to fully undestand the method you propose so I can implement it myself.
I get lost in the ninth line:
    `ON gkg.V2Locations CONCAT('%', c.country, '%')`
shouldn't there be a logical operator between the two arguments following the ON? If not I dont fully understand the reason of the `CONCAT`. Isn't this function call meant to replace the conditional operators in my original code that get the data only related to the countries of interest?

Comment: Are you using the legacy interface or the standard interface?  I added the missing operator in the `ON` clause.

Comment: I have tried it under both using legacy and standard SQL. The issue seems to be in the two consecutive `SELECT`, I get the following error:
`Error: Encountered " "SELECT" "SELECT "" at line 7, column 13. Was expecting: ")" ...`. I am not sure whether you can run "multiple queries" like that in BigQuery.
Thanks for clarifying the `ON` issue.

Comment: I am pretty sure I've done that in Big Query, but I don't have easy access right now to check.

Comment: It worked once I used Mikhail Berlyant's code, which is just an adaptation of yours, I am marking his as the answer, in case someone wants to just copy and paste the the code.